# Виджеты Wordpress. Как обернуть контент виджета произвольным html?

Tags: wordpress

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => esc_html__( 'Сайдбар', 'zone-theme' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
    'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add widgets here.', 'zone-theme' ),
    'before_widget' => '<div class="sidebar-widget">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<div class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</div>',
  ) );
```

делаю.

вот что выводит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**В коде могу добавить обертку для тайтла виджета(before_title+a_t) и еще могу добавить обертку для всего виджета(before_widget+a_w). Как обернуть своим html, ul тег(контент виджета). Как я знаю нет такого параметра типа before_content и after_content. Или есть ?)**

мне нужна такая структура кода

```
<div class="sidebar-widget">
  <div class="widget-title">...</div>
  <div class="widget-content"><ul>...</ul></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Самое простое решение в after_title прописать div для контента '</div><div class="widget-content">' и в after_widget добавить еще один закрывающий тег '</div></div>'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По хорошему в таких случаях гораздо проще и эффективнее определять соответствующую вёрстку в самом виджете.

```
public function widget($args, $instance)
{
   $title=$instance[“title”];
   echo “<aside class=\”widget widget_recent_entries\”>”;
   echo “<h2 class=\”widget-title\”>$title</h2>”;
   // Это уже контент виджета
   echo “<p>”.Date(‘d’).” “.Date(“M”).” “.Date(“Y”).”</p>”;
   echo “</aside>”;
}
```

Параметры sidebar предназначены для настройки не столько самих виджетов, сколько их отображения в нём. Как-то так...

Comment: ну это капец кнч. В каждом файле виджета надо будет менять получается ?

Comment: Ну это же WordPress...